# Calcular porcentagem entre 2 números

Tags: php, datetime, data, porcentagem

Tenho que fazer um sistema de porcentagem aonde tenho 2 datas em `TIMEUNIX`, sendo a data final `($cota->ultimo_recebimento)` e o dia atual que eu pego com a função `time()` do PHP. Tentei fazer assim:

```
<?php
echo ((time() / $cota->ultimo_recebimento) * 100).' %';
?>
```

e também assim

```
<?php
echo (100 - (time() / $cota->ultimo_recebimento * 100));
?>
```

Mas nenhum me deu uma porcentagem certa.

Apenas preciso que ao passar os dias ele com base no `$cota->ultimo_recebimento` vai incrementando a porcentagem. Após a data atual for maior ou igual ao `$cota->ultimo_recebimento` então ele mantém em `100%`

Tenho 3 variáveis

```
$atual = time();
$primeiro = $cota->primeiro_recebimento;
$ultimo = $cota->ultimo_recebimento;
```

Comment: Se eu entendi corretamente, você não tem dados suficientes para saber esse percentual. Para saber o percentual do tempo corrido você precisa de 3 datas: inicio, atual e fim; ou de 2 intervalos: tempo total (fim - inicio), tempo para fim (fim - atual), só com esses 2 valores (atual e fim) não tem como.

Comment: Tenho `$cota->primeiro_recebimento` sim, esqueci de colocar

Comment: @Berriel com esses dados, você consegue ajudar ?

Comment: Veja se a resposta te ajuda...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue o cálculo

```php
// exemplo
$inicio = 1453248000; // 20 de janeiro de 2016
$fim = 1454112000; // 30 de janeiro de 2016
$atual = 1453507200; // 25 de janeiro de 2016

// no seu caso:
// $inicio = $cota->primeiro_recebimento;
// $fim = $cota->ultimo_recebimento;
// $atual = time();

$total = $fim - $inicio;
$tempoRestante = $fim - $atual;

$percentualParaTerminar = ($atual >= $fim) ? 1 : $tempoRestante / $total;
$percentualCorrido = 1 - $percentualParaTerminar;

echo $percentualParaTerminar; // saída: 0.7
echo $percentualCorrido; // saída: 0.3

echo ($percentualParaTerminar * 100) . '%'; // saída: 70%
echo ($percentualCorrido * 100) . '%'; // saída: 30%
```

Comment: **$atual = '1455206086'; // 11 de fevereiro de 2016** --- **$inicio = '1455188400'; // 11 de fevereiro de 2016** --- **$fim = '1456315200'; //24 de fevereiro de 2016** e o resultado é **0.98412318068868** porque ?

Comment: Porque falta 98,4% do tempo para o fim... você quer o % do tempo para o fim, ou o % do tempo que já passou?

Comment: @AlissonAcioli mudei o exemplo para ficar mais claro

Comment: Deixei assim http://pastebin.com/6y7RA8uS e deu certo :) ... Obrigadooo!

Comment: @AlissonAcioli sem problemas :)